# Webpack returns undefined when requesting external resource

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd

I am trying to make a request to an external resource in a webpack module (`my_request.js`), but when I call the method from my `main.js` script, it returns undefined. Anyone experienced this problem or have any thoughts?

```
// my_request.js
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    var makeRequest = function() {
        $.get('http://api.example.com', function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    };
});

// main.js
require(['./js/my_request'], function(request) {
    var r = request.makeRequest();
    console.log(r); // returns undefined
});
```

Comment: The response returns within `makeRequest`, I can see this if I log to the console before the return statement. The problem seems to be exporting the return value to `main.js`.

Comment: Yes, that inner callback function does return the value, but so what? It doesn't return the outer `makeRequest` function, which has already returned before the callback function was even called.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, thanks. As you might be able to tell I'm not a js developer :)